# importing correct AssertThat method for Robolectric Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am attempting to run the test from Robolectric.org's [Writing Your First Test](http://robolectric.org/writing-a-test/) page. The test in question looks like this:

```
  @Test
  public void clickingLogin_shouldStartLoginActivity() {
    WelcomeActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(WelcomeActivity.class);
    activity.findViewById(R.id.login).performClick();

    Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(activity, WelcomeActivity.class);
    assertThat(shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivity()).isEqualTo(expectedIntent);
  }
```

I get this compile error: `Cannot resolve method 'assertThat(android.content.Intent)`.

The two possibilities I see for importing this method are [`org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/MatcherAssert.html) and [`org.junit.Assert.assertThat`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html), neither of which have a single-argument `assertThat` method as is being used in this Robolectric test.

My app's `build.gradle` has these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

What framework/library is this test using?

Comment: It is neither `junit` or `hamcrest` assertions. I think it is `Android AssertJ` or just `AssertJ`

Comment: So it was.  Thank you!  If you want to post an answer; I'll accept.

Comment: You can also use google truth for assertions: https://github.com/google/truth

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is neither `junit` or `hamcrest` assertion API. I think it is `Android AssertJ` or just `AssertJ`:

```
testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1'
```

Comment: The gradle dependency was `testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1'`.  Versions 2 and 3 aren't compatible with Android.

Comment: Updated answer with correct dependency. Check also Android AssertJ from Square

Comment: Would have been nice if the robolectric tutorial mention this instead of StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

follow the following and the issue should go away. Put the first line in you gradle build file

```
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

public class SomethingTest {
     @Test
     public void testSomething() {
           assertThat(true, 1>1); 
     }
}
```

this link should provide more details also 
[Android Studio and Robolectric](http://nenick-android.blogspot.com/2015/03/android-studio-110-and-robolectric-30.html)